# Exercise - Maven by Example book

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to study Maven, and so I created a simple web application as provided on the book "Maven by Example", and in that applicaton I have the simple-weather having simple-model as a dependency, inside the simple-parent maven project.

I just copied the pom.xml (making just adjustments to the hibernate artifact version), and when I run "mvn install" on the "simple-model", it builds ok,  but when I run "mvn install" on the "simple-weather" it doesn't build ok because it says it doesn't find the packages related to the simple-model dependency.

NOTE: If I create two eclipse projects and relate simple-model" it compiles ok, so there is no issue related to the projects compilation.

See both pom.xml. I suppose the issue is on the pom.xml, but I have no idea of what to do. I already tried to fix in many ways, but got no success at all.

I already copied even the group and artifact id from the simple-model to the simple-weather to guarantee it was not a typing issue. :-(

//simple-model -> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multispring</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>simple-model</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Simple Object Model</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

//simple-weather -> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multispring</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>simple-weather</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Simple Weather API</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multispring</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

See the error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project simple-weather: Compilation fai
lure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \mavenTest\ch-multi-spring\simple-parent\simple-weather\src\test\java\or
g\sonatype\mavenbook\weather\yahoo\YahooParserTest.java:[8,43] error: package or
g.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.model does not exist
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the source in simple-model actually correct?

Please note that Maven is not complaining for unresolved dependency.  Dependencies seems correct and it is compilation error that it cannot find the package `org.sonatype.mavenbook.weather.model`.  It is mostly because such package is available neither in the simple-web project itself, nor in its dependencies (i.e. simple-model).

Check the JAR created in simple-model to see if it contains correct content.

Comment: You are right! Now I have to find out why that is happening. Thanks!